# Outlook Addin is not working for new opened instance

Tags: c#, vsto

I had developed an outlook addin, which is working fine in functionality wise. However if I open an outlook item by double click and click my addin in opened instance, it is again saving the selected outlook item in Original Outlook instance. So what I have to do, to save the opened outlook item using my addin in the popped up instance?? please let me know if anyone need anymore additional details[image: ![function]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LuP7U.jpg)

[image: highlighted [![ribbon xml][addin in Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06Eys.png)[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06Eys.png)